# Как сортировать рандомный список?

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Всем привет.
Юзер вводит определенные данные из которых создается список. Но вводит их в рандомном порядке. Например, получается список:

```py
['name', 'age', 'id ', 'hobbies']
```

А мне в итоге нужно отсортировать этот список так, чтобы получилось:

```py
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
```

Я сделал так, чтобы это сортировалось циклом for, создавая при этом новый список. Но мне кажется, что это костыльный способ. Может есть что-то проще?

PS:
Извиняюсь, что без кода (с телефона пишу) Но, надеюсь, проблема понятна

Comment: `‘id’, ‘name’, ‘age’, ‘hobbies’` -- какая-то хаотическая сортировка -- нет упорядочения ни по алфавиту, ни по длине слова.  Если нужен жёсткий порядок, можно использовать словарь, в котором значениями будут индексы.

Comment: В том и проблема, что она хаотичная. Непонятно за что зацепиться, чтобы отсортировать… А если со словарем, то как? Можно пример?

Comment: Что значит хаотичная сортировка?

Comment: Как уже предложено, либо ключами по полному совпадению, либо смотрите в сторону частичного совпадения, например по первым двум буквам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from random import shuffle

a = ['name', 'age', 'id', 'hobbies']


def sort_key(val):
    return {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 1,
        'age': 2,
        'hobbies': 3
    }.get(val)


for _ in range(10):
    shuffle(a)
    print(a)
    a.sort(key=sort_key)
    print(a)
    print('-------------------------')
```

```
['age', 'hobbies', 'id', 'name']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['name', 'id', 'age', 'hobbies']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['id', 'hobbies', 'age', 'name']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['name', 'hobbies', 'id', 'age']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['id', 'hobbies', 'age', 'name']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['name', 'id', 'hobbies', 'age']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['age', 'name', 'id', 'hobbies']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['id', 'age', 'hobbies', 'name']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['age', 'hobbies', 'name', 'id']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
['age', 'id', 'hobbies', 'name']
['id', 'name', 'age', 'hobbies']
-------------------------
```

Comment: Кстати, можно и без отдельной функции, прямо вот так: `a.sort(key={'id': 0, 'name': 1, 'age': 2, 'hobbies': 3}.get)`

Comment: @CrazyElf, век живи, век учись - дураком помрешь. Спасибо